# How to convert an integer to its ascii equivalent

Tags: c++, random, char, integer, ascii

Context: I am making myself a password generator in c++, basically it uses rand to generate numbers, and these numbers correspond directly to ASCII characters.

So, generating the numbers is easy, but i need to convert this to their ASCII equivalents to actually make a usable password.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    //Initializing variables.
    int type = 0;
    int character = 0;
    char print = character;

    //Generator.
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
    {
        type = rand()%(3-1+1)+1;//Determines: 1 = Uppercase, 2 = Lowercase, 3 = Number.
        if (type == 1)//If Uppercase.
        {
            character = rand()%(90-65+1)+65;//Determines Uppercase character to be generated.
            cout<<print<<endl;
        }
        if (type == 2)//If Lowercase.
        {
            character = rand()%(122-97+1)+97;//Determine Lowercase character to be generated.
            cout<<print<<endl;
        }
        if (type == 3)//If Numerical.
        {
            character = rand()%(57-48+1)+48;//Determines Number to be generated.
            cout<<print<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

In the code i posted above, you can see i last tried blatantly telling the program that the variable "character" needs to be used as an actually character.

Ok so there seems to be a bit of confusion.
Rand generates a number say between  65 and 90. These numbers correspond to capital letters on the ASCII table. I want to print to the console the letter, not the generated number.

Comment: Try using a mapping table.

Comment: You are assigning your random value to the variable `character`, but what you are printing is the variable `print`.  The assignment `print = character` at the beginning only sets `print` to the value that `character` has at that point in the code, which is 0.  Changing `character` later won't update `print`.  This is a pretty fundamental fact about computer programs.

Comment: By the way, you haven't actually explained what your problem is...

Comment: The question is unclear. "ASCII equivalents"? Could you give an example of the conversion you're trying to do? Do you want to convert `103` into "103" (`char[]` or `std::string`?), or `65` into 'A", or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write this

```
char print = character;
```

you tell the compiler that you want it to initialize variable `print` to the *current* value of variable `character` (which happens to be zero at the time). If you want the current value to be set to a variable of different type, you need to do it after a reassignment of `character`:

```
character = rand()%(90-65+1)+65;//Determines Uppercase character to be generated.
print = (char)character;
cout<<print<<endl;
```

You do not have to do reassignment, though, because a cast directly before printing will be sufficient:

```
character = rand()%(90-65+1)+65;//Determines Uppercase character to be generated.
cout<<(char)character<<endl;
```

**Note:** although it is fine to use decimal values of ASCII characters, the code becomes easier to read if you use character constants instead:

```
character = rand()%('Z'-'A'+1)+'A';
```

Comment: Thankyou very much. Also using 'Z' instead of 90 makes it sooo much easier for me to read. :)

Answer (score 1):

may be try by replacing

```
cout<<print<<endl;
```

by

```
cout<<(char)character;
```

Then you will understand what you missed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Jay Kumars answer this is I believe an implicit/explicit conversion

Here is an example I tested with my code, it functions to this end.

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)  {
     cout << (char)('0' + 17 + i) << "-->\t"; // implicit conversion
}
```